# How to read and write XML elements "as is" with JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, jaxb

I have to process some "ugly" XML pieces and would like to do so using JAXB to save some time.

Let's say my documents are structured like this:

```
<root a="1" b="2" c="3">
<header a="1" b="2" c="3">
<info/>
<more info/>
</header>
<body>lots of nested elements in here</body>
</root>
```

I would like to process a couple of attributes from the root Element and the Children and bring them into a new document with a different structure. The problem is: I need to have the content of **body** untouched in my new document.

Is there any way (when unmarshalling / marshalling) to take the content of an element "as is"?

Comment: Would you mind using XSLT for the job? Because, what you seem to want is what XSLT does best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to have parts of your XML unmarshalled into general-purpose DOM objects, rather than JAXB-generated classes. Take a look at [this link](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Avoid_strong_databinding.html#Mapping_to_DOM) and [this one](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/section_2_2_16_1-Elements-With-Any-Type.html#Elements%20With%20Any%20Type).

That example is for when you're generating your Java classes from a W3C Schema, using inline custom bindings. You can have the custom bindings in a separate file and have that used by XJC when generating the Java classes.

Naturally, in case you code the classes yourself, the same can be reached using the proper annotations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@XmlAnyElement` annotation to preserve portions of the XML as DOM nodes.  You can also use a `DomHandler` to keep the XML fragment in another format such as a String.

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xmlanyelement-and-non-dom-properties.html

Comment: Aw man, I was busy searching through your blog to find appropriate links when you posted :D [This one](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html) seems relevant as well.